# R - How to delete rows with certain dates

Tags: r, dataframe, row, subset

I have a dataframe like this:

```
x1= c("Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 2", "Station 3", "Station 3", "Station 3")
x2= c("1993-06-08", "1994-06-09", "1982-06-10", "1993-06-11", "1992-06-12", "1997-06-13")
x3= seq(5, 30, length=6)
x4= seq(4, 16, length=6)
x5= seq(10, 60, length=6) 

testframe = data.frame(Station=x1, Date=x2, Morning=x3, Noon=x4, Evening=x5) 

testframe[,2] = as.Date(testframe[,2], format="%Y-%m-%d")
class(testframe$Date)
```

Now I want to remove all rows that are recorded before 1993-01-01.

I did this:

```
index = testframe[,2] >= "1993-01-01"
```

And it gives back the right list of True and False, but I dont know how to go on.

I tried this, but without success:

```
new = testframe[index]
new = [-c(testframe[index]),]
```

Can somebody help? I know it should be really easy, but I dont get it.

Comment: `testframe[index,]` (or `testframe[!index,]` depending on whether `index` is `TRUE` or `FALSE` for the rows you want to keep).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main concept to keep in mind: `data.frame[rows, columns]`

## base R

`testframe[testframe[["Date"]] >= "1993-01-01", ]`

## dplyr

`library(dplyr)`

`testframe %>% filter(Date >= "1993-01-01")`

## data.table

`library(data.table)`

`setDT(testframe)`

`testframe[Date >= "1993-01-01", ]`

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I know that concept with row and columns, but I didnt know that I also need it in this case.